# Перехват события touchEvent

Tags: java, android, ui, touch

Есть разметка такого вида:

```
<LinearLayout>
     <RecyclerView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Мне нужно чтобы touch event по `RecyclerView` перехватывался `LinearLayout'ом`. Т.е. в идеале если список находится на нулевой позиции и происходит касание сверху вниз, родительский лэйоут должен обрабатывать касания сам, иначе передавать касания списку, для нормального скролла.

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть проблемы. Почему нельзя отрабатывать касание напрямую в RecyclerView?

Comment: для того, чтобы если список находится на нулевой позиции, и пользователь тянет список вниз, сделать свайп родительского контейнера.